# Solution such that complex function W is a straight line in W-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

I have a problem understanding a part of https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0005247.pdf on page 59.

Here, 
$$
\widetilde{W}=-N\sigma(\log\sigma-1)-t\sigma.
\label{SlogS}
$$
is a function of the complex parameter $\sigma$. $N$ is an integer, while $t$ is a complex parameter. Using the notation 
$$
t_{\it eff}=t+N\log\sigma,
$$
and 
$t_{\it eff}-N=e^{i\gamma_{\it eff}}|t_{\it eff}-N|$,
we have $$
\widetilde{W}=-e^{i\gamma_{eff}(\sigma)}\sigma|t_{eff}(\sigma)-N|
\\=-\bigg[\textrm{Re }(e^{i\gamma_{eff}(\sigma)}\sigma)+i\textrm{Im }(e^{i\gamma_{eff}(\sigma)}\sigma)\bigg]|t_{eff}(\sigma)-N|\tag{1}
$$
The authors claim that the solution for $\sigma$ such that we have a straight line in the $\widetilde{W}$-plane is 
$${\rm Im}\Bigl(e^{i\gamma_{\it eff}(\sigma)}\sigma\Bigr)=
{\rm constant},$$
how does one show this to be true?

**EDIT**

There is additional information which I did not include previously, which is consistent with what Andrew D. Hwang deduced. There is a physical constraint (B-type supersymmetry) which insists that the straight line is parallel to the real line, i.e., it is *horizontal*. In other words, we should have $\textrm{Im} (\widetilde{W})=\textrm{constant}$. This was discussed earlier in the paper (above equation 3.13). However, from $(1)$ it seems to me that this requires 
$${\rm Im}\Bigl(e^{i\gamma_{\it eff}(\sigma)}\sigma\Bigr)|t_{eff}(\sigma)-N|=
{\rm constant},$$
and not what is given above.

Comment: After a few minutes of perusing page 59 of the linked paper (and a few earlier pages): Just above equation (6.28), the authors write, "...is the preimage of _the_ straight line..." (emphasis added), when straight lines are obviously not unique. Not knowing the physics, my best guess is that "...a $D$-brane preserving the $B$-type supercharge...is the preimage of a _horizontal_ line...", since this is a simple criterion consistent with the claim in your question. Does this make sense in the context or the paper? Particularly, is the $B$-type supercharge the imaginary part of $\widetilde{W}$?

Comment: Yes, it is the preimage of a horizontal line, but it still does not seem correct, I will edit my question shortly to explain why.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: On further thought, I agree with you; when checking the calculations myself, I forgot that $|t_{\text{eff}} - N|$ depends on $\Sigma$.

Comment: It seems that $|t_{eff}(\sigma)-N|$ is actually approximated to be a constant, because on the same page they say that \sigma is taken to have large expectation values.